# Modify nan index in pandas

Tags: python, plot, pandas

This question is somewhat related to [Visually separating bar chart clusters in pandas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13983498/visually-separating-bar-chart-clusters-in-pandas)

I am reading and plotting the tmp.csv file:

```
pol1 pol2 pol3
perim 0.54 0.64 0.40
mst 0.08 0.12 0.12
treeadd 0.25 0.34 0.35
health 0.14 0.17 0.17
bisort 0.48 0.56 0.56
em3d 0.14 0.17 0.17

g721d 1.41 2.58 2.58
mesa 1.16 1.8 1.8
epic 1.82 2.43 2.43
jpege 1.18 1.68 1.68

gzip 1.15 1.43 1.45
vpr 0.19 0.24 0.24
gcc 0.82 1.11 1.15
mcf 0.05 0.05 0.05
crafty 0.67 1.17 1.17
```

with:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

from pandas import *
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from numpy import zeros

# Create original dataframe
df = read_csv('tmp.csv',sep='\s')

print df

df.plot(kind='bar')
plt.show()
```

and I get:

```
         pol1  pol2  pol3
perim    0.54  0.64  0.40
mst      0.08  0.12  0.12
treeadd  0.25  0.34  0.35
health   0.14  0.17  0.17
bisort   0.48  0.56  0.56
em3d     0.14  0.17  0.17
nan       NaN   NaN   NaN
g721d    1.41  2.58  2.58
mesa     1.16  1.80  1.80
epic     1.82  2.43  2.43
jpege    1.18  1.68  1.68
nan       NaN   NaN   NaN
gzip     1.15  1.43  1.45
vpr      0.19  0.24  0.24
gcc      0.82  1.11  1.15
mcf      0.05  0.05  0.05
crafty   0.67  1.17  1.17
```

and:

[image]

Note the separation of the clusters with the empty lines. This is the effect I want. 
Is there a way to replace the 'nan' label with "" in the x-axis?

I tried:
    df.rename(index={'nan': ""})

However there is an assertion failing

```
assert(new_axis.is_unique)
```

Probably because there are multiple 'nan' indexing the df. Ideas?

-Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of modifying the `DataFrame`, perhaps just change the matplotlib xtick labels:

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

df = pd.read_csv('tmp.csv', sep = '\s')
df.plot(kind='bar')
locs, labels = plt.xticks()
plt.xticks(locs, [d if d==d else '' for d in df.index], rotation = 25)
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Even if this is not exactly what I was looking for, it did work.

Comment: Any idea how to go about actually changing the df index? Several of my problems stem from the fact that I cannot use equality with np.nan . --Thanks

Comment: I think what you are asking is related to this [open issue](https://github.com/pydata/pandas/issues/2067). Sorry; I don't have any good idea for a workaround.